# using jQuery to keep navigation buttons hover state when corresponding page is loaded

Tags: jquery, button, navigation, indicator

i'm a HTML/CSS coder and im just terrible with the Javascript but I try and it makes my websites much more effective and better looking. I've given my buttons an effect here's the HTML and JQUERY for my buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css"    media="screen" />
    #info {
        width:250px;
        height:auto;
        min-height:658px;
        background:url('images/bgdiv.gif') no-repeat right center;
        float:left;
        }

        #info ul {
            width:225px;
            height:auto;
            margin-top:75px;
            display:block;
            }

        #info ul li a {
            font-family:helvetica;
            font-size:17px;
            font-weight:bold;
            letter-spacing:1px;
            text-align:center;
            color:#fff;
            width:85px;
            height:27px;
            line-height:29px;
            background:#3d526c;
            float:right;
            list-style-type:none;
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
            }
<style>

<title>Alex S. Construction</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="info">
    <ul id="categories">
        <li><a href="index.html">Interior</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="exterior.html">Exterior</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="gates.html">Gates</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="doors.html">Doors</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="misc.html">Misc.</a></li><br>
    </ul>
</div><!--INFO-->
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript that effects the button,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#info ul li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"width": "150"}, "fast");
    },  function() {

    $(this).stop().animate({"width": "85"}, "fast");

var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);  
var href = $('#info ul li a').each(function(){  
    var href = $(this).attr('href');  
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){  
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #gallery';  
        $('#gallery').load(toLoad)  
    }  
});

$('#categories ul li').click(function(){  

var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #gallery';  
$('#gallery').hide('fast',loadContent);
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);  

function loadContent() {  
    $('#gallery').load(toLoad,'href',showNewContent())  
}  
function showNewContent() {  
    $('#gallery').show('normal');  
}  
return false;  

});  
}); 
});
```

im using jquery to also load the pages main content DIV in, I want to acheive the effect of the navigation buttons staying put in their hover state when the correspnding page is loaded. So that way the user can know what category he's on and have the indicator also be the navigation to be more effecient in space usage but still effective. Thank You very much for reading I hope to hear back soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#info ul.catagories a').click(function () {
    $('div#info ul.catagories a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

style:

```
#selected {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Near pseudo code... but something close to that would work...

Comment: I found the solution without using java because it was to complicated and even that didn't work out for me. thank you though i appreciate your time.